# 403 This action is unauthorized

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy realizando un proyecto tipo red social, le explico mi problema, lo que quiero hacer es: yo tengo mi empresa y yo solo yo puedo ver mi información de la empresa entonces he creado una **policy**  llamado **EmpresaPolicy** y tengo un **model** llamado **DatosEmpresa** y tengo el un **controlador** llamado **DatosEmpresaController**

Ya tengo el login y ahí todo bien entonces lo que pretendo hacer es que cuando yo este en mi perfil de la empresa me salga información de mi empresa la que yo he registrado, pero me sale también la información de los otros usuario que yo he creado aqui les dejo lo que he hecho aclaro soy nuevo y voy aprendiendo en el camino.

```
<?php

 namespace App\Policies;

 use App\User;
 use App\DatosEmppresa;
 use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class EmpresaPolicy
{
  use HandlesAuthorization;


 public function __construct()
 {
    //
 }

 public function MiEmpresa(User $user, DatosEmpresa $empresas)
 {
    return $user->id == $empresas->user_id;
 }
}


<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\DatosEmpresa;
use App\Policies\EmpresaPolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

 class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {

 protected $policies = [
     DatosEmpresa::class => EmpresaPolicy::class,
 ];

 public function boot()
 {
    $this->registerPolicies();

    
 }
}


<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\User;
  use App\DatosEmpresa;
  use App\Categoria;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Http\Requests\CreateDatosEmpresaRequest;

  class DatosEmpresaController extends Controller
  {

    public function index()
    {
      $empresas = DatosEmpresa::all();
 
      $this->authorize('MiEmpresa', $empresas); 

    return view('empresa.index',[
        'empresas' => $empresas
    ]);
}
```

Entonces el mensaje que me sale es

> 403 This action is unauthorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando declaras el método **`MiEmpresa`** le estás indicando que reciba dos instancias.

- Una del modelo **`User`**
- Otra del modelo **`DatosEmpresa`**

Entonces cuando construyes el método **`index`** este mismo deberá recibir [también una instancia](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers) del último modelo listado quedando así:

```
index(DatosEmpresa $empresas)
```

Por otro lado se me hace raro que si quieres ver solo las empresas que tú has registrado entonces estés cargando una consulta que los seleccione todos, lo más sencillo sería:

Pasar de esto:

```
$empresas = DatosEmpresa::all();
```

A esto:

```
$empresas = DatosEmpresa::whereUserId(auth()->id())->get();
```

Para solo traer aquellas empresas donde la llave del **`user_id`** sea igual al ID del usuario que inicio sesión.